# Kafka windowed stream make grace and suppress key aware

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I currently have a simple stream of data, for example:

```
|-----|--------|-------|
| Key | TS(ms) | Value |
|-----|--------|-------|
|  A  |   1000 |   0   |
|  A  |   1000 |   0   |
|  A  |  61000 |   0   |
|  A  |  61000 |   0   |
|  A  | 121000 |   0   |
|  A  | 121000 |   0   |
|  A  | 181000 |  10   |
|  A  | 181000 |  10   |
|  A  | 241000 |  10   |
|  A  | 241000 |  10   |
|  B  |   1000 |   0   |
|  B  |   1000 |   0   |
|  B  |  61000 |   0   |
|  B  |  61000 |   0   |
|  B  | 121000 |   0   |
|  B  | 121000 |   0   |
|  B  | 181000 |  10   |
|  B  | 181000 |  10   |
|  B  |   1000 |  10   |
|  B  | 241000 |  10   |
|  B  | 241000 |  10   |
|-----|--------|-------|
```

this is also the order I publish the data in a topic, the value isn't really an integer but an avro value but the key is a string.

My code is this:

```
KStream<Windowed<String>, Long> aggregatedStream = inputStream
   .groupByKey()
   .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1)).grace(Duration.ZERO))
   .count()
   .toStream();

aggregatedStream.print(Printed.toSysOut());
```

The output of the `print` is:

```
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000003]: [A@0/60000], 1
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000003]: [A@0/60000], 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000003]: [A@60000/120000], 1
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000003]: [A@60000/120000], 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000003]: [A@120000/180000], 1
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000003]: [A@120000/180000], 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000003]: [A@180000/240000], 1
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000003]: [A@180000/240000], 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000003]: [A@240000/300000], 1
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000003]: [A@240000/300000], 2
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000003]: [B@240000/300000], 1
[KTABLE-TOSTREAM-0000000003]: [B@240000/300000], 2
```

It seems that the grace period applies globally independently of the key of the stream, what I expect instead (if possible) is to receive all the 10 window counts of key A and the 10 window counts of key B.
In a way that the grace only closes windows based on the key of the stream.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `grace` and `suppress` uses a global timestamp for each partition, so it's not possible to have a different one per each key.

What's possible instead is to disable the grace period and use a custom transformer instead of the regular `suppress` to do be able to suppress by key.

For example this is part of our code:

```
KStream<String, ...> aggregatedStream = pairsStream
    .groupByKey()
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1)))
    .aggregate(...your aggregation logic...)
    .toStream()
    .flatTransform(new TransformerSupplier<Windowed<String>, AggregateOutput, Iterable<KeyValue<String, SuppressedOutput>>>() {
        @Override
        public Transformer<Windowed<String>, AggregateOutput, Iterable<KeyValue<String, SuppressedOutput>>> get() {
            return new Transformer<Windowed<String>, AggregateOutput, Iterable<KeyValue<String, SuppressedOutput>>>() {
                KeyValueStore<String, SuppressedOutput> store;

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
                    store = (KeyValueStore<String, SuppressedOutput>) context.getStateStore("suppress-store");
                }

                @Override
                public Iterable<KeyValue<String, SuppressedOutput>> transform(Windowed<String> window, AggregateOutput sequenceList) {
                    String messageKey = window.key();
                    long windowEndTimestamp = window.window().endTime().toEpochMilli();
                    SuppressedOutput currentSuppressedOutput = new SuppressedOutput(windowEndTimestamp, sequenceList);
                    SuppressedOutput storeValue = store.get(messageKey);
                    if (storeValue == null) {
                        // First time we receive a window for that key
                    }

                    if (windowEndTimestamp > storeValue.getTimestamp()) {
                        // Received a new window
                    }

                    if (windowEndTimestamp < storeValue.getTimestamp()) {
                        // Window older than the last window we've received
                    }

                    store.put(messageKey, currentSuppressedOutput);
                    return new ArrayList<>();
                }

                @Override
                public void close() {
                }
            };
        }
    }, "suppress-store")
```

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax yeah wanted to add the example then forgot about it. You think it's possible to propose this to integrate it in kafka? This could be very useful when processing data from different inputs (which clocks might not be in sync) or when loading historical data for new keys

Comment: Maybe. But not sure if it's required. You could just increase the grace period accordingly to get a single result per key and not drop any data. In general, the data pattern you have cannot be expected but seems to be a very special case. Usually, keys interleave randomly and you would just set grace period accordingly high.

Comment: I think I have a very realistic use case, where tracking stream time per partition is problematic. Suppose we're loading historical data (always promoted as a key feature of Kafka) into a topology which has a processing step, where the key is extended (e.g. by some payload data). The resulting topology would have a repartitioning step. What now could happen is that processing instances of the first subtopology are running faster than others, causing the input partitions for the second subtopology to be unordered (even though the partition is still ordered by key).

Comment: To not reject records of the "slower" keys, a very grace period was required in our case, which seems not to be ideal.

Comment: Note that some instances running fast than other is very likely when having similar amounts of partitions and keys. This can, in particular, be the case when processing historical data as we might want to use many instances and thus many partitions to get our results as fast as possible. Say, for example, we have 30 different keys and use 20 partitions to utilize 20 instances. Now it's likely (or in this case certain) that some partitions have more keys (and data) than others and are thus slower.